# How to use on the spot Japanese input with fcitx and mozc? (as opposed to over the spot) (16.04)

Tags: xubuntu, input, japanese, fcitx, mozc

Where can I switch to on the spot input style when using fcitx and mozc for Japanese?

By on the spot I mean displaying the letters at the cursor location as I type.
Now, when trying to type Japanese, letters aren't shown at the cursor. They are shown in a separate sub-window [like this](https://developer.blender.org/D1570#34275). Only after selecting a spelling for the word typed it gets pasted after the cursor. AFAIK it's called over the spot style of input.

I've setup my Japanese input according to https://moritzmolch.com/2287.
I'm using on Xubuntu (Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS). On the spot was the default, but then one day it changed to over the spot. I don't recall making any changes to the configuration myself.

Comment: Try remove "~/.config/fcitx" and reboot.